# Solving a system of equations with a parameter.

Tags: linear-algebra

> We consider for $ a \in \mathbb{C}$ the system of equations:
>
> $$(S_a) : 
> \begin{cases}
> x + y + z = \alpha \\
> x + a^2y + z = \beta \\
> x + y + a^3z = \gamma 
> \end{cases}$
> $$
>
> 1. What the matrix $A_a$ of the system $(S_a)$?
> 2. What is the rank of $A_a$?
> 3. For what values of $a$ does the system admit a unique solution? Determine 
>      this solution.
> 4. Solve the system of equations for $a = -1$.

---

1. The matrix of the system is 
   $$A_a = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 \\
   1 & a^2 & 1 \\
   1 & 1 & a^3 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
2. Rank of $A_a$.
   Reducing $A_a$ to the echelon form gives: $$A_a = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1       & 1 \\
   0 & a^2 - 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0       & a^3 - 1 \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$
   hence $\text{rank}(A_a) = 3$.
3. Values for which the system admits a unique solution. 
   We have: $$\det(A_a) = (a^2 - 1)(a^{3} - 1)$$

The system admits a unique solution if and only if $a \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -1, 1 \} $. The solution is: $(x,y,z)$ such that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x =& \frac{\det(A_x)}{\det(A_a)}\\
y =& \frac{\det(A_y)}{\det(A_a)}\\
z =& \frac{\det(A_z)}{\det(A_a)}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
with:

$\det(A_x) = \begin{vmatrix}
\alpha & 1   & 1   \\
\beta  & a^2 & 1   \\
\gamma & 1   & a^3 \\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
\alpha & 1   & 1   \\
\beta - \alpha & a^2 - 1 & 0 \\
\gamma - \alpha & 0 & a^3 - 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} = \gamma(a^2 - 1) - (\beta - \alpha)$.

$\det(A_y) = (\beta - 1)(a^3 - 1)$.

$\det(A_z) = (a^2 - 1)(\gamma - 1)$.

**My questions:**

1. Is my calculation of $\det(A_x)$ coorect?
2. Is there a simpler/ quicker way to determine the solution?
3. Solving $(S_a)$ for $a = -1$:

We have $\det(A_{-1}) = 0$, which means the matrix $A_a$ is not invertible and I can't solve it with the matrix method.

$$(S_{-1}): \begin{cases}
x + y + z = \alpha \\
x + y + z = \beta \\
x + y - z = \gamma \\
\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}
x + y + z = \alpha \\
x + y - z = \gamma \\
z \in \mathbb{C} 
\end{cases}\\ \iff 
\begin{cases}
x + y = \alpha - z \\
x + y = \gamma + z \\
z \in \mathbb{C}
\end{cases} \iff 
\begin{cases}
x + y = \alpha - z \\
y \in \mathbb{C}   \\
z \in \mathbb{C}   \\
\end{cases}$$

The set of solutions of $S_{-1}$ is:

$S = \{ (\alpha - y - z, y, z)\;|\; y,z \in \mathbb{C} \}$

Are my answers correct?

Comment: Is there a $z$ missing in your last equation of the given System?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, thank you.

Comment: The rank of $A$ depends on the value of $a$. There are values of $a$ for which the matrix does *not* have full rank, as you ought to have have noticed when solving part 3.

Comment: @amd The rank of $A$ is 1 if $a \in \{-1,1\}$ and 3 if it's not. Correct?

Comment: $a\in\mathbb C$, so there are other roots of the polynomial besides these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. $\operatorname{rank}A_a=3$ if $a^2\ne 1$ and $a^3\ne -1$, i.e. if $a\ne 1,-1, j, j^2$ (the non-real cube roots of $1$.

If $a=1$, the matrix$A_a$ has rank $1$.

If $a=-1, j, j^2$, it has rank $2$.

The determinants are false: you should find, applying Sarrus' rule:
\begin{align}\det A_x&=\alpha(a^2-1)(a^3-1)-(\gamma-\alpha)(a^2-1)-(\beta-\alpha)(a^3-1)\\
&=\alpha(a^5-1)
\end{align}
Also,
$$\det A_y=(\beta-\alpha)(a^3-1), \qquad\det A_z=(\gamma-\alpha)(a^2-1).$$

*Edit* :

For the solutions of $S_{-1}$, you have a linear system of rank $2$, so the set of solutions is either empty, if the compatibility conditions are not satisfied, or a affine subspace of dimension $1$. You forgot the compatibility conditions and obtain a set of solutions of dimension $2$.

The simplest way  to solve is to obtain the *reduced* row echelon form of the *augmented matrix*:
\begin{align}
&\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&1&\alpha\\1&1&1&\beta\\1&1&-1&\gamma
\end{array}
\end{vmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&1&\alpha\\0&0&0&\beta-\alpha\\0&0&-2&\gamma-\alpha
\end{array}
\end{vmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&1&\alpha\\0&0&0&\beta-\alpha\\0&0&1&\frac12(\alpha-\gamma)
\end{array}
\end{vmatrix}\\
\rightsquigarrow{}
&\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&0&\frac12(\alpha+\gamma)\\0&0&0&\beta-\alpha\\0&0&1&\frac12(\alpha-\gamma)
\end{array}
\end{vmatrix}\rightsquigarrow
\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&1&0&\frac12(\alpha+\gamma)\\0&0&1&\frac12(\alpha-\gamma)\\0&0&0&\beta-\alpha
\end{array}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align}

so the compatibility condition is $\alpha=\beta$, and the solutions are given by
$$z=\frac12(\alpha-\gamma), \quad y=\frac12(\alpha+\gamma)-x. $$

Comment: Can you check my answer for question 4. Solving the system for $a = -1$? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The final part is wrong. The system has rank $2$, so the space of solutions is an affine subpace of dimension $3-2=1$, and you find a solution which depends on $y$ and $z$. Furthermore, the sole parameter $\alpha$ appears,where is only one compatibility condition: $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: Can you edit your answer by elaborating more on this please?

Comment: $\begin{cases}
x + y = \alpha - z \\
x + y = \gamma + z \\
z \in \mathbb{C}
\end{cases} \iff
\begin{cases}
x + y = \frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2} \\
y \in \mathbb{C} \\
z = \frac{\alpha - \gamma}{2}
\end{cases} \iff
\begin{cases}
x = \frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2} - y \\
y \in \mathbb{C} \\
z = \frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2}
\end{cases}$.

Can I take $y = \frac{\alpha + \gamma}{2}$ so the set of solutions can be one dimensional?

Comment: Yes it is? There's a small error for the final $z$. Please see the way to solve using only the augmented matrix.